# How do I create a Javascript function that pushes user inputted (numerical) data from a table into an array, and displays the average of that data?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a table that prompts the user to input numerical data into a table.

What I need is for each row of user data to be calculated, and the sum to be display in the column "Results", the number of data points to be totaled in the column "# of Samples" and the average displayed in the column "Average."

I would like of each total to be displayed rounded to the nearest hundredth (eg. 1.00). Except for the "# of samples column" which can display a regular number.

I am not very good with Javascript at all and am hoping to get some insights from you guys. So far I had started to try to write the beginnings of a function, but it does nothing so far, and I do not know how to proceed.

```js
var resultsRow = [];

function calculateTable() {
  var result = document.getElementById('text-input').value;
  resultsRow.push(result);
  //display
  document.getElementById('text-input').innerHTML = average;
}
```

```css
table {
  height: 600px;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 5em auto;
  border: 1px black solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table th {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 25px;
}

table td {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 25px;
}

#text-input,
#result-box {
  width: 4em;
}

.button-div {
  width: 70px;
  margin-left: 690px;
  padding-top: 50em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
}

#result,
#average,
#sample-count {
  border-color: red;
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>Paperwork Averager</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--Make a table doofus-->
  <table>
    <tr id="headings">
      <th>Chemical</th>
      <th>12am</th>
      <th>4am</th>
      <th>8am</th>
      <th>11am</th>
      <th>2:30am</th>
      <th>6pm</th>
      <th>9pm</th>
      <th>Extra Sample</th>
      <th>Results</th>
      <th># of Samples</th>
      <th>Average</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Pre CL2 Free</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td id="result"></td>
      <td id="sample-count"></td>
      <td id="average"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pre CL2 Total</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td id="result"></td>
      <td id="sample-count"></td>
      <td id="average"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Iron/Influent</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td id="result"></td>
      <td id="sample-count"></td>
      <td id="average"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cl2 Free (behind filters)</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td id="result"></td>
      <td id="sample-count"></td>
      <td id="average"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cl2 Total (behind filters)</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td id="result"></td>
      <td id="sample-count"></td>
      <td id="average"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Influent pH</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td id="result"></td>
      <td id="sample-count"></td>
      <td id="average"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CL2 FREE (GST)</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td id="result"></td>
      <td id="sample-count"></td>
      <td id="average"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CL2 TOTAL (GST)</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td id="result"></td>
      <td id="sample-count"></td>
      <td id="average"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>pH (GST)</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td id="result"></td>
      <td id="sample-count"></td>
      <td id="average"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Iron (GST)</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td id="result"></td>
      <td id="sample-count"></td>
      <td id="average"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cl2 Effluent (Sink)</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td id="result"></td>
      <td id="sample-count"></td>
      <td id="average"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cl2 Influent (Sink)</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td id="result"></td>
      <td id="sample-count"></td>
      <td id="average"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Flouride (Sink)</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td id="result"></td>
      <td id="sample-count"></td>
      <td id="average"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Effluent pH (Sink)</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td id="result"></td>
      <td id="sample-count"></td>
      <td id="average"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Effluent Iron (Sink)</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td id="result"></td>
      <td id="sample-count"></td>
      <td id="average"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alkalinity (Sink)</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text-input"></td>
      <td id="result"></td>
      <td id="sample-count"></td>
      <td id="average"></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <div class="button-div">
    <button type="button" onclick="calculateTable();">Calculate!</button>
    <button type="button">Clear</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Something like `resultsRow.push(inputs.value)` then `resultsRow.reduce((a,b)=>{a + b}) / resultsRow.length`, but I would think you would want this per line and are you looking to get the average per line due to the number of inputs that are filled out when you hit the overall `calculate` button?

Answer (score 0):

First you can wrap the inputs and submot button inside a form, then pass the function to the onsubmit on the form. You can give the input names, then you can get the values in the function.

don't put id text-input on multiple html elements and id should only be used once

here my example. I only added the names to two html inputs, the rest is up to you

```
function calculateTable(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  const formData = new FormData(event.target);
  let totalValues = 0;
  let entryAmount = 0;

  for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    if(pair[1]){
    totalValues += Number(pair[1]);
    entryAmount ++
    }
  }

  //display
  document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = totalValues / entryAmount;
}
```

https://codepen.io/jeltehomminga/pen/WNJYYdv?editors=1111